# Android debugging -Nexus 7 - status offline in eclipse- mac

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-debug, adb

I just want to test my android application in my Nexus 7 device in my mac.
I connect the Nexus 7 tablet to my mac through USB connection. While I try to run , its status is offine.

I also tried to run my android application in Windows machine. There I installed one driver for Nexus 7. Windows detect the Nexus and I can able to run my application in Nexus.

Is there any special driver needed for Mac?

Please provide me the best way t overcome the issue

Comment: Maybe it will be helpful: http://www.wugfresh.com/faqs/how-to-fix-adb-device-is-listed-as-offline-on-android-4-2-2/

Comment: @coelho let me take a look and try the solutions

Comment: @coelho how to open Advanced utilies..

Comment: It is not part of Android, it is part of the Nexus Root toolkit: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1766475

Answer (score 3):

several suggestions :
1. You have to authorize every machine you use since android 4.2
2. Check if you need to update your sdk.
  You have to update to the proper API level and to usb driver (under extras -> Google usb driver).         Then change the driver of your nexus 7 to the new one. You can find it at your android-sdk folder.
3. If that won't help you call to : 'adb devices' (Windows commend - I guess that it has to be the same at mac)

Answer (score 1):

**Did you check on your device:** 
Enable USB debugging on your device.
On most devices running Android 3.2 or older, you can find the option under

```
Settings > Applications > Development.
```

On Android 4.0 and newer, it's in `Settings > Developer options`.
**Note:** On Android 4.2 and newer, Developer options is hidden by default. To make it available, go to `Settings > About` phone and tap Build number seven times. Return to the previous screen to find Developer options.